# Can't change Timer declared in using block

Tags: c#, timer, using

I want to declare a Timer with a using, to take advantage of automatic Disposal. But I want the timer to change its own interval to ensure it doesn't tick while the callback is still running

The problem is that I can't reference the timer from inside the callback.

```
string s = "sample object";
using (Timer t = new Timer(
    state =>
    {
        var nextTime = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(interval);
        // do work on object in method scope, so thought to declare timer callback here
        var x = s;
        // but timer callback should call Change on itself
        t.Change(Math.Max(nextTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now).Milliseconds, 100), Timeout.Infinite);
        // ^^^ Use of unassigned local variable 't'
    }, null, interval, Timeout.Infinite))
{
    var finishTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10);
    while (finishTime > DateTime.Now)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(333);
        Console.WriteLine($"{(finishTime - DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds} remaining.");
    }
}
```

The following syntax allows me to change the timer from within the callback, but I lose the scope of the first example (can't access object o anymore), and it isn't declared in a using.

```
private static Timer s = new Timer(new TimerCallback(c), null, 1000, Timeout.Infinite);

private static void c(object state)
{
    s.Change(1000, Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

Is there any way around this? I'm trying to access the local variables defined alongside the timer, and declare it in a using block.

Comment: Why are you inexplicably using `dynamic`?

Comment: To make a mcve. Note the function `Foo` as well, which is also not part of my actual code. Just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: I wonder if the timer would survive past the using clause anyway. Even if you manged to push it in somewhere.

Comment: Why not have a flag declared outside the timer which you can use to keep track of whether your logic is executing or not? If it's not executing, run the logic. If it is executing, skip that tick. For example `bool isRunning = false;`. It changes how often and when your execution occurs, but depending on your use case this might be acceptable.

Comment: If you want to block the thread then you shouldn't be using a timer to begin with.  Either you want to do your work asynchronously, or you want to do it synchronously, but trying to do it asynchronously while synchronously waiting for that asynchronous operation to finish is just making trouble for yourself.  Either block the thread and do your work in the loop, without using a timer, or use a timer and don't block the thread.

Comment: @mason That changes the semantics.  WIth the OP's code the next operation will run in "interval" time after it finishes, with yours it will run in "interval - time since the last event fired", which could be a fair bit sooner (half, on average, if the time it takes is actually random).

Comment: @user6144226 It wouldn't survive past the end of the `using`, but of course it doesn't need to.  That's the whole point, in fact.

Comment: @Servy Yes, I'm aware of that. Probably should have disclosed it in my comment. Depending on the use case, it may be acceptable.

Comment: Depending on the framework version I bet you could achieve something like this with Task.Delay & ContinueWith

Comment: @user6144226 But again, the code needs to do the work synchronously, so you don't want to use an asynchronous framework.  (Unless they plan on changing their code to make it no longer synchronously wait,)

Comment: It's part of an instrumentation measurement loop. Where instruments are measured at some interval, the timer interval, and the UI is updated periodically with the remaining time in the while loop. I don't want to synchronize these actions because one is UI and one is not. In my example Console.Write is in place of a UI invocation. When the update loop expires, the measure timer should also stop. Hence the using.

Comment: @djv In that case your code is most certainly wrong.  You need to *not block the UI thread* by synchronously waiting as you are.  You need to ensure that the UI is updated using asynchronous tools.  There are plenty of options, ranging from a timer from a UI framework (that fires the event in the UI thread) to using `await`, or any number of other possibilities, depending on the specifics of what you're actually doing.

Comment: @Servy it's just raising an event which is handled on the UI. The code above doesn't run on the UI. I'm just going to use a subroutine for the timercallback and make the locally scoped variable private class level.

Comment: @djv So then you're creating a new thread just to have it sit around doing nothing while you wait for this timer to finish.  Don't do that.  You shouldn't be starting the additional thread in the first place, and then you should be using asynchronous tools to update the UI while the operation is ongoing.

Comment: @Servy you're right... the thread is already in the background so the measurement can be done in a while loop and I can handle the timing by sleeping before the next measurement. Thanks

Comment: @djv Again, you should not be creating background threads just to have them sit there doing nothing for the entirety of their lifetime.  That's bad design.  You should be using asynchronous tools for updating the UI when it needs to be updated so that you don't need to create a thread just to have it sit there and never do anything productive.

Comment: @Servy yeah, I got it. I believe I need to sleep because I want to measure at a maximum frequency. I can either allow a timer to do it but then as you said I am wasting a thread. Or do it in the current thread, but then I need to sleep the current thread between measurements. I don't know how to avoid sleeping a thread either way.

Comment: @djv The way to not have a thread just sleeping all of the time is to *not create the thread* in the first place, since you don't actually need it to do any work.  Then you don't have a thread just sleeping.

Comment: @Servy I want to measure instruments once every 1000ms (configurable). It may take 100ms to 500ms to perform measurements. Once measurements are done I don't want to immediately measure again because I want 1000ms between measurements. So I sleep the thread until it's ready to measure again. How can I do this better?

Comment: @djv You use a timer, rather than having a thread sleep.

Comment: @Servy Right, but the timer would run on a different thread, so I'm still adding a new thread. And the original thread has nothing to do other than raise the update UI event every 333ms for 10 seconds, and do what in between? (sleep?) That was my original idea.

Comment: @djv The *tick* event is going to run on another thread (or the UI thread, if you use a timer from whatever UI framework you're using).  That's it.  No thread is sitting around doing nothing between tick events.  Again, the whole point here is that you *shouldn't* have the calling thread just sitting around sleeping the whole time.  Don't block the thread, do the work asynchronously.  You don't need to *find* something to do to waste the thread's time.  *Don't have a thread at all*, so that there is nothing to have its time wasted.

Comment: @Servy The current thread is originating as an awaited Task from a UI thread (can't change this framework). Inside this task I had a `System.Threading.Timer` (so it's not on the UI). It is querying many instruments in a Parallel.Foreach which are blocking calls over USB mainly. It has to happen exactly / at most once per 1000ms (though this is configurable). I also want to update the UI at least twice as fast as that by raising an event handled on the UI. The point is I don't have anything else to do on my background thread between measurements, hence the sleep.

Comment: I'm removing the Timer which will reduce the number of running threads by 1, and putting the parallel loop inside a while. I still need to sleep this thread though. How can I not? I think it has to do with the overall design in which this thread is already running in a task being awaited. Since I can't change that I don't know how to avoid sleeping the thread.

Comment: @djv You're doing the exact opposite of what you need to do.  Rather than creating a thread just to have it do nothing but sleep all the time, you need to use a timer.  You then *create no background thread at all*, and just use your timer to perform the periodic work that you want to do. If you have multiple things that you want to do at different periods, then create two timers, rather than one timer and one background thread that just sleeps all the time.

Comment: @Servy I have no choice but to start in a background thread originating from Async / Await. This background thread is doing other things before this (it is a mfg automated test script testing lasers fyi) such as a current setting / wait / measure loop. The one I'm working on now is a fixed current, periodic measure loop. The thread really has nothing to do while it's waiting to measure the next time. I am bound by running inside a method void Run() which is being awaited in a task. It is one of many other automated tests, so I can't change this design.

Comment: @djv If you can't change how it's started then you can at least let the thread complete right away, since you don't actually need to use it to do any more than start one (or possibly two) timers, after which point it can go right back to the thread pool to go on doing productive work (or to go away, if it's no longer needed) rather than forcing it to do nothing even though you no longer need it.

Comment: @Servy It's something along the lines of the UI calling `await Task.Factory.StartNew(IScript.Run)`, and inside of `Run` there are multiple test sequences which each need to measure instruments multiple times in discrete intervals. Immediately after `IScript.Run` returns, the UI then awaits `IScript.SaveData()`. So everything needs to be done in Run(). I can't change this. It's not perfect that the script runs on one thread which must be  put to sleep for the vast majority of its lifetime, I agree. I just wanted to know how best to declare the timer in this imperfect scenario.

Comment: @djv All the better then.  Right now you're scheduling a new thread all so that you can have it sitting around doing nothing because you want an asynchronous operation.  Since you want an asynchronous operation *make an asynchronous operation*.  You have no need for a thread to do that.  Don't write a synchronous method and run it in a thread pool thread, make an *inherently* asynchronous method that doesn't use *any* threads, and doesn't make anything sleep.  You can then await *that* method.

Comment: @Servy so from within `IScript.Run` I should await the measurement? Then how do I handle the timing?

Comment: @djv If you want an asynchronous operation that completed after a fixed period of time you can use `Task.Delay`.

Comment: @Servy Ok great that looks like what I need. I really appreciate all the help. I will try to make this method properly asynchronous tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something hacky - you can declare `Timer t = null` before the `using`.

This will result in the use of a "modified closure", but despite that it actually works:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int interval = 1000;
            string s = "sample object";
            Timer t = null;

            using (t = new Timer(
                state =>
                {
                    var nextTime = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(interval);
                    // do work on object in method scope, so thought to declare timer callback here
                    Console.WriteLine("Doing work with " + s);
                    // but timer callback should call Change on itself
                    t.Change(Math.Max(nextTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now).Milliseconds, 100), Timeout.Infinite);
                }, null, interval, Timeout.Infinite))
            {
                var finishTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10);
                while (finishTime > DateTime.Now)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(333);
                    Console.WriteLine($"{(finishTime - DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds} remaining.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However this whole approach seems a bit dodgy!

I would advise that you DON'T do this - find an approach that doesn't need such use of a timer (pay heed to Servy's comments).

Comment: This may work. But I'm still interested in knowing if there is a better solution.